# Is possible change value of a string variable and hold permanently this value without saving it in any file for the next restart?

Tags: java

```
String name=null;    
public void firstUse(){

if(name!=null)
{
   System.out.println("Hello "+name);
}else
     {
      Scanner scan=new Scanner();
      System.out.println("Insert your name please:");
      String ins=scan.nextLine();
      setName(ins);
}
}
```

can I set the name only one time by saving it directly in the code?

Comment: This is a very unusual request. I suspect this isn't what you really need to do. Perhaps you could give us some more information on *why* you think you need to do this?

Comment: Before asking *is possible to do foo in Java?* ask yourself *is this possible to do foo in the language I'm most experienced with?*

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: If it's not going to be stored in a file *anywhere*, where do you think the information will live when you turn the computer off?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I'm not asking to be snide. I am interested in the original problem that you are trying to solve so that we can provide other possible solutions.

Comment: with javassist i can add/modify code in a method and i want to know how i can save changes, if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't store it 'directly in the code'.  The code may well be somewhere you don't have write access to.

There is an api for storing things on the computer without creating a file yourself -- THAT information is almost certainly in a file *somewhere*, but not one that you have to manage or create.  Look at the Preferences API;  it is a lot like storing something in the Windows Registry (which is, in fact, what the Preferences code does on a Windows system).

But that's as close as I can come to what it sounds like you're asking

Comment: I just need to know if it was possible or not

Answer (score 0):

you can't. its not possible to store it anywhere thats not in a file. what you can do is store it inside the jar file so they don't see it.

Comment: This is not a viable solution for sensitive data (such as passwords or credit card numbers) because someone can *still* pull the information out of the JAR file without too much work.

Comment: he never said it was private information. in this case he wants to hold a name.

Comment: And that's not private information? Besides, this is clearly an example for illustration not the OP's real code.